# Read IP-layer headers using Java sockets

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, udp, ip

Is there a way (in Java) to read IP-layer headers (I'm interested in src & dst IPs), using TCP or UDP socket?

I know it's possible using `pcap` (packet capture), but I didn't find a way to do it using sockets.
What's the reason behind that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the operating system level, you need [raw sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774668/what-is-raw-socket-in-socket-programming) to access IP-layer headers. But fortunately raw sockets don't exist in pure Java so you need native code to make the relevant syscalls.

There are Java libraries that use a JNI component for the native calls. One example (which I used successfully in the past) is [Rocksaw](https://www.savarese.com/software/rocksaw/).

Answer (score 0):

You can just open /dev/socket as a InputStream and read data coming into to socket.