# How to "break out" of bottom-level protocols in sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I recently found out about raw sockets (sockets without TCP/UDP), and looking at the structure of any socket message, I realized that the "raw" sockets are not truly raw - they still have the bottom level (IP) protocol. How can I use sockets without that bottom level protocol in c++?

I do not want to use any protocol at the internet level - i.e. not IPV4, IPV6, or ICMP - I would want to custom implement any one of those.

EDIT...

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774668/what-is-raw-socket-in-socket-programming) answer actually answers my question. I wish I'd known that raw socket had a double meaning...

Comment: are you talking about posix sockets? boost sockets? Afaik there is nothing about sockets in the standard library

Comment: @idclev463035818 I'm a bit new... What are posix sockets? What I mean is a socket that can connect to other computers without use of IPV4, IPV6, or any other bottom-level protocol.

Comment: you tagged c++, but it is not clear what sockets you are talking about.

Comment: I tagged c++ because that's the language I intended to use. What do you mean by its not clear what sockets I'm talking about?

Comment: Would that work for wireless packets?

Comment: No, I'm looking for sockets lower even then that, where I could actually custom-implement the IPV4/IPV6 protocols.

Comment: @nerdguy: *"I'm looking for sockets lower even then that, where I could actually custom-implement the IPV4/IPV6 protocols."* -  these are AF_PACKET raw sockets which are mentioned in the answer I've linked to. I recommend that you get an understanding of the OSI or TCP model first so that you can understand the answer though, i.e. what means layer 2 and layer 3 etc.

Comment: As it stands this seems like an xy-problem.  What are you actually trying to do here? If you look at the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_4:_Transport_Layer), which level do you really want to inspect/modify?

Comment: @G.M. The lowest one possible.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes, that does actually answer my question. Sorry I didn't find that answer myself

Comment: Just you wait. Underneath IP will be some sort of MAC frame. And underneath that... Who can say?

Comment: @user4581301 I don't think I'll go that deep... Custom MAC framing sounds a lot like MAC spoofing

Comment: If you're not manually specifying the voltage for each pin on the Ethernet connector, you're not really trying :)

Comment: Saying things like that will drive the people on Server Fault insane

Comment: @user4581301 turtles all the way down

Comment: @user4581301 The MAC level is the lowest level that the CPU can manipulate.